# How can I add a criteria to this function, so it only sums columns if they exist in the table?

Tags: javascript

The way this function is, it gets columns whose `class` is `size_qty` and outputs the total at the end of each row and also to the grand total at the bottom. However, when a table is loaded,which doesn't contain `size_qty`, it overwrites `qty`'s value with 0, instead of just not calculating at all.

I am new to this, so I can't think of a way to add a criteria.

```
function sum_row_qty(el) {
  let rowTotal = 0
  if (el) {
    let parent = el.closest("tr")
    parent.querySelectorAll('.size_qty').forEach(function(e) {
      rowTotal += parseFloat(e.value)
    })
    parent.querySelector('.qty').value = rowTotal
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll("#tableRows > tr > td:first-child input").forEach(sum_row_qty);
  }
}
```

Comment: How about `parent.querySelector('.qty').value = (rowTotal)? rowTotal: '';` ...if `rowTotal` === 0 (false), write empty string?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, Thanks for the edit and for the suggestion. When there are no ```size_qty```, it should allow for the value coming with the dataset to remain. Currently, these ```qty```'s gets overwritten.

Comment: Then just wrap it in a `if ( rowTotal ) { parent.querySelector('.qty').value = rowTotal; }` block.

Comment: Thank you, @bloodyKnuckles! It works! Can't quite get why, as ```rowTotal``` is ```0```... I'll try digesting it. Thanks!

Comment: `0` is equivalent to `false`. It is clearer to write `if ( 0 === rowTotal ) ...`.